# How to exclude UserDir paths from ProxyPass

Tags: apache

I want to configure apache UserDir cooperating with ProxyPass, that is, want all requests but  starting with `/~` passed to proxy.

Firstly I have ProxyPass settings for a Rails application as bellow:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
```

and, now I want to add public_html UserDir setting to this.

In other words, I want the requests to `http://example.com/hoge/fuga` goes to rails app, but those to `http://example.com/~user`refer to refer to `/home/user1/public_html` directory.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem by adding the line bellow to the apache config;

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/~ !
```

Comment: I realized folder icons were missing when I used this. Apparently apache provides them under /icons, and I was able to restore them using `ProxyPassMatch ^/~|^/icons/ !`

Answer (score 0):

Does the below work?

```
ProxyPass /~ !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
```

`!` will tell mod_proxy not to forward requests beginning `/~`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tried it already and it doesn't seem to work...